# Trouble combining IF, AND, OR, COUNTIF statement into one

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I wrote a simple formula in column H that checks if the Item# in col. A is on a sheet named SharePoint. If it's not, the cell will say 'Add to SP.'

> =IF(COUNTIF(SharePoint!N:N,A2)=0,"Add to SP","")

But what I really want is for the cell to say this only if sheet SharePoint doesn't haven the Item# AND columns D or F say one of the phrases in the OR statement below. I added a combination of AND and OR statements to the above formula to accomplish this. This formula is in column I.

> =IF(AND(COUNTIF(SharePoint!N:N,A2)=0,OR(D2="Transferred",D2="Needs Validation",D2="No PPAP Required",D2="Closed W/O Approval",F2="Supplier Late")),"Add to SP","")

[Here are a couple of test cases.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ktlx.png). Neither item# is in sheet SharePoint (which the simple formula in col. H correctly diagnoses), AND they have one of the phrases in the OR statement. So column I should say Add to SP, but the formula just returns a #N/A error.

If I'm not mistaken, I don't think there are any syntax errors. I feel like the logic of the formula makes sense, so what have I done wrong? Did I make some sort of error when I combined the AND and OR statements?

Comment: Do some troubleshooting to figure out what's not meeting your expectation. Does =IF(AND(TRUE,OR(D2="Transferred",D2="Needs Validation",D2="No PPAP Required",D2="Closed W/O Approval",F2="Supplier Late")),"Add to SP","") produce good results? If so, why? If not, why not?

Comment: Using the Formula Evaluator can really help get to where this goes awry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Successfully recreated the error by placing `=NA()` in F2. This is the cause: the formula is testing for equality between the value "Supplier Late" and cell F2. Cell F2 has the special value `#N/A` (not a text value).

Try this:

`=IF(NA()="OK","Good","Bad")` is `#N/A`
`=IF(OR(TRUE,NA()="OK"),"Good","Bad")` is `#N/A`

There are no "lazy" (short-circuit evaluations) using the logic functions (or operators), `AND` and `OR` in formulas (or VBA). All items are evaluated first and the logic is applied last.

To fix this, use a wrapper on all equality tests where the situation could arise:

`IFNA(test,)`

No need to provide a second argument to `IFNA` (zero is returned and tests as False).

`=IF(AND(COUNTIF(SharePoint!N:N,A2)=0,OR(D2="Transferred",D2="Needs Validation",D2="No PPAP Required",D2="Closed W/O Approval",IFNA(F2="Supplier Late",))),"Add to SP","")`

Comment: +1 Really thorough answer. Nice job

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear and is exactly what I wanted to know. I learned a lot. Thanks again.